# What is the difference between .addBack() and .parent()?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between .addBack() and .parent()?

It seems like they both just traverse up one level and select the element.

Answer (score 4):

The results of `parent` get the DOM that is direct DOM parent of the current selection, while `addBack` get the previous selection when you're doing chaining in jQuery.

Using following example:

```
<div class="the-one">
  <div class="child-1">
    <div class="grandchild-1"></div>
    <div class="grandchild-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
  <div class="child-3"></div>
</div>
```

If you run `$('.the-one').find('.grandchild-1').parent()` you would get `child-1`.

If you run `$('.the-one').find('.grandchild-1').addBack()` you would get `the-one` and `grandchild-1`.

`addBack` is usually used when you're transversing down your DOM in chaining and you want an easy way to go back to previous selection and doing another transversing.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where you are coming from.
`parent()` will always select the direct parent element, `addBack()`'s result depends on the result of the previous selector:

> .addBack( [selector ] )
>
> Returns: jQuery
> Description: Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set, optionally filtered by a selector.

Check out the following jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vGAq5/2/

The first alert will have selected all following siblings of Number two, adding back number two.
The second aler will have selected all following siblings of Number two, and take its parent (instead of adding it to the result set).

Answer (score 3):

Completely different methods:

```
addBack() - add the current selection to the previous one and merges those selections

parent() - selects the direct parent of the current selection
```

Check the official docs:

http://api.jquery.com/addBack/

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Basic example:

consider the html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
console.log($('#child').parent()); // return the div#parent selection

console.log($('#child').addBack()); // return the div#child selection - it merges the div#child with the previous selection (which happens to be empty)
```

Comment: The API for addBack says "Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set".

Comment: @nipponese - well it's the same.. adding A to B is the same as adding B to A.. or i don't understand the comment

Comment: Late, I know, but re: @nipponese -- `parent` adds back the "previous" set **based on _DOM_**. `addBack` adds back the previous set **based on _time_**, so to speak, your _most recent selection_. See if [this fiddle helps](https://jsfiddle.net/t1aoergp/1/).